# Managing multiple Node.js versions with nvm in a tmux session

Tags: node.js, tmux, nvm

### Short question

How can I get [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to work with [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net)?

### Path Problems

As [MarkHu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699665/markhu) surmised in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221965/95592), the problem is related to the PATH. Below is a comparison of the path in bash before entering [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) and after starting [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net). (I replaced each : in the path with a line break to make it easier to compare.)

[image: Bash and tmux PATH comparison]

Now I'm curious as to:

1. Why are `/usr/local/sbin` and `/Users/matthew/bin` are duplicated in the path?
2. Why did `/Users/matthew/.nvm/v0.11.5/bin` along with `/usr/local/sbin` and `/Users/matthew/bin` get moved to the end of the path?

### Background

I'm running OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion. I installed [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) v1.8 and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) using:

```
brew install tmux
brew install node
```

I then decided I wanted to manage multiple node version, so I installed [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) using:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
```

If I'm not in a [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) session, [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) appears to work correctly. When I start a [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) session though, it finds the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) installed by [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead of using the [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) version. Any thoughts on how to get [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to work with [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net)?

```
$ which node
/Users/matthew/.nvm/v0.11.5/bin/node
$ tmux
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$ nvm use v0.11.5
Now using node v0.11.5
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem and am ready to dig into tmux's source to see what I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your $PATH environment var before and after.

There is a difference between setting it in ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc depending on how you have those configured.

Also, you may want to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15453/using-environment-variables-in-tmux-conf-files if you think other node.js-related vars may need to be set.

Answer (score 3):

I just run:

```
nvm deactivate
nvm use x.x
```

That seems to work. You can script out the needed version depending on the project you're working on.

Comment: actually after `nvm deactivate` the node version shows correct but all scripts stopped running